# changing tablix width in reports

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-tablix

In MS Reports I need to hide the columns in the tablix, but I need to keep the tablix width as it was. By default, if I hide the columns in the tablix it will automatically reduce the width.

I also need to increase some other columns width when I hide the columns.

I will add some Screenshot here.

This is the Original report.
[image]

So I need to hide all columns that has the value zero. So I did it and I got the result as
[image]

So now I want to keep the tablix width as it was in the original report by adding space (increase the width ) of the "Design NO" column (2nd Column) .

Pls help me ,
Thank you..!!

Answer (score 1):

The only way to hold the tablix width is to have something occupy the space. I suggest using conditional formatting to use a white font. If you don't have data for that cell, use an expression that checks if the field that is normally there is empty and return a constant value that gives you the width you need. If you need to increase the width of other columns, you're going to have to add embedded spaces or something. The dynamic sizing of columns depends on having something occupy the space, even if it's spaces or white text.

Comment: I added the white space to enlarge some column while I hide the other column but it only increasing the height of the column not increasing the Width. So it doesn't keep the original width of the tablix.

Comment: I have updated my question with screenshots. Please give me any solution.