# SSRS automatic extension columns depending on the parameters - tablix

Tags: reporting-services, parameters, width

I have a table and a graph next to each other in a line.
I can choose one or more of 5 columns which can be displayed by using multiple values in parameters. But when I'll choose 4 of 5 I have white area between chart (graph) and tablix (table), what I don't want. I want to expand these columns to initial tablix size. And the same in case less number of columns. Is it possible expand them depending on chosen parameters?

(Edit:) Or how to change width of column depending on expression? If I can do this, my problem will be solved.

Or another idea is to expand chart on whole width - it could be between tablix and the end of page.

Any ideas how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is unfortunately not possible in SSRS without the use of a hack. To quote the "accepted" answer from [this MSDN thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/9e6043f1-c458-4540-be59-d37b02feab8a/dynamic-column-width-for-a-report?forum=sqlreportingservices):

> This is a common request and I definitely see the value in it.  However, we didn't get to this for SSRS 2008.  Please feel free to file a feature request (or add votes to an existing request) on the connect.microsoft.com.

As far as I know this hasn't changed in SSRS 2012, though someone may correct me on this.

The thread mentioned above holds several workardounds, ranging from ugly to UGLY. One other lead (possibly even a duplicate question?) is [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11070577/419956) where it's suggested to not hide the column but make the text have the same color as the background o.O